# Is there a difference in how Google Apps Script is interpreted when run as a Time-Driven script and when run from the Editor?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script function which seems to be interpreted differently when run from the editor, and when run in a Time-Driven script. When run as a scheduled script, it returns the following error and I frankly do not understand why.
*Error Exception: Invalid argument: yyyy-MM-dd'T'[object Object]:00Z at isBetweenTimeWithTz(Code:24:24)*

When the function is run from the editor, I get the output i would expect, e.g.
*0 '2022-01-13T00:50:00+0100' '2022-01-13T01:30:00+0100' Wed Jan 12 2022 18:50:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) Wed Jan 12 2022 19:30:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)*.

```
function isBetweenTimeWithTz(from_t="00:50", to_t="01:30", tz="Europe/Prague"){
  now = new Date();
  from_str = Utilities.formatDate(now, tz, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'${from_t}:00Z`);
  to_str = Utilities.formatDate(now, tz, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'${to_t}:00Z`);

  from_dt = new Date(from_str);
  to_dt = new Date(to_str);

  is_between = from_dt <= now & now <= to_dt;

  console.log(is_between, from_str, to_str, from_dt, to_dt);

  return is_between;
}
```

For scheduling, I use this function:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('isBetweenTimeWithTz')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(1)
      .create();

    console.log("Trigger triggered");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference I noticed when I printed the parameters is that, the first parameter in the time-driven script was overwritten with this:

```
{authMode=FULL, second=3.0, triggerUid=2100292014431267688, minute=24.0, timezone=UTC, hour=16.0, day-of-month=13.0, day-of-week=4.0, week-of-year=2.0, month=1.0, year=2022.0}
```

To avoid the first parameter being overwritten, you can add a placeholder parameter that will contain the above value.

#### Modification:

```
function isBetweenTimeWithTz(placeholder="", from_t="00:50", to_t="01:30", tz="Europe/Prague"){
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: great tip, thanks a lot! Do you happen to know if this is a bug or Google Apps Script feature?

Comment: I rewrote my original code so that the scheduled function does not have any parameters which seems to solve the issue. Once again, thanks a lot for your sharp observation.

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny, I can't say for certain if it's a bug or not. I haven't came across with any documentations mentioning the overwriting feature of it. I never even imagined it was overwriting the first parameter before testing. If this is a feature, it should be mentioned at the start of it since not knowing this will have negative implications to the script as a whole.

Comment: it would be nice to receive a warning when trying to schedule a function with arguments. I would not mind even if Google Apps Script threw an error. Much better than when a function behaves unexpectedly.

Comment: It's a documented feature for all triggers.  I make a habit of including `e` as the first parameter for any function that I might launch from a trigger.

Comment: I just never thought that the event trigger object would overwrite the parameters. I have used event objects especially on onEdit triggers but did not know it works that way when you have other parameters. It's a first, thanks for the clarification @AaronDuniganAtLee

Answer (score 1):

All triggered functions are passed an `event` parameter, as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events):

> When a trigger fires, Apps Script passes the function an event object as an argument, typically called `e`

It's sometimes useful to use the data from that parameter within the trigger execution.  [The event object for a timed trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events) contains data about the time at which the trigger was launched.

Comment: So it’s a feature after all :-)) I can certainly see a use case for using data from the event argument yet I still can’t get my head around the fact that I am passing the function named arguments that are overwritten by e. Why is e added as the first argument, and not the last?

Comment: I think e is defaulted to the first parameter that's why it gets overwritten. I too am using this parameter and i just know today that it overwrites the first parameter. I am using this but I have no other parameters being passed so I haven't encountered this issue.

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny In JavaScript, arguments with default values ("named" args) are still positional arguments.  The triggering mechanism is calling something like `isBetweenTimeWithTz(e)`.  The first parameter of `isBetweenTimeWithTz`, regardless of its name, will be assigned the value of `e`, and since the other arguments in the signature are absent, they will be assigned `null`. You can see this if you call `isBetweenTimeWithTz('test')` from within your own script and then log the argument values.